# FastAPI - How to read an json file while using UploadFile

Tags: python, api, fastapi

```
from typing import List, Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI(debug=True)
@app.post("/uploadfiles/")
def create_upload_files(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
     json_data =  ??  upload_file ?? 
     result = model().calculate(json_data)
     return { "estimation": result}


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    content = """
<body>
<form action="/uploadfiles/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="upload_file" type="file" multiple>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)
```

I have the above FastAPI app. I need to upload a json file. Thus the upload_file is a json file. Also the model() instance uses a method calculate that takes as input json data. I struggle on how to decode the upload_file from Fast_API to dictionairy format.

I tried
upload_file.read()
but this returns a bytes array

Could you please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the standard `json` module to parse the content by using [**`json.load()`**--(Doc)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) from an uploaded JSON file as

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import json

app = FastAPI(debug=True)


@app.post("/uploadfiles/")
def create_upload_files(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    json_data = json.load(upload_file.file)
    return {"data_in_file": json_data}
```

Thus, you will have the JSON contents in your ***`json_data`*** variable.

Alternatively, you can use [**`json.loads()`**--(Doc)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function as

```
json_data = json.loads(upload_file.file.read())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ;) I think you need a .read() on json_data = json.load(upload_file.file.read() Can you please edit your answer to close the question it you aggree?

Comment: No. If you are using ***`json.load(...)`***, you must use `upload_file.file` (btw, `json.load(...)` and `json.loads(...)` are different)

Comment: @A.Papa Updated the answer with few more info.