# How can I read uploadfiles when using threading in fastapi

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, fastapi

Following the explanations given here [FastAPI - How to read an json file while using UploadFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933560/fastapi-how-to-read-an-json-file-while-using-uploadfile) and there [FastAPI runs api-calls in serial instead of parallel fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion) I switched to threading instead of async.

I removed the `await`s in my program and now get an error when trying to read the uploaded file:

```bash
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UploadFile.read' was never awaited
  result = context.run(func, *args)
```

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()

def validate_configuration(config_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        content = config_file.read()  # used await before and now causes an attribute error
        print(content)
        configurations = yaml.safe_load(content.decode())
        return JSONResponse(content={"message": "Done"}
    except Exception as exc:
        return JSONResponse(content={"error": str(exc)}, status_code=400)
```

But of course I cannot use `await` anymore, because I am no longer using `async` so what is the intended way to resolve this?

Comment: Does `config_file.file.read()` do what you want? The exposed direct methods are the async helpers, so if you don't need async support, perform any operation directly on the included file-like object. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile